# Python likeless in dataframe rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I am facing a issue in Python.
I have a dataframe  and I would like to only get likelihood on different columns.
As an example, I have:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({
                'name':['Dupont','Dupant','Darang','BA','Scatt','Sieb'],
                'ID': ['789985','789852','9852220','015220','015221','10022']
              })
```

[image]

I would like to know how I could process this dataframe to get below result:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
                'name':['Dupont','Dupant','BA','Scatt'],
                'ID': ['789985','789852','015220','015221']
              })
```

df

[image]

Any idea or suggestion would be very appreciated.

Comment: What is the logic to drop the rows?

Comment: @mozway it seems to be drop duplicates by keeping first from this example? could be wrong though

Comment: @EmiOB there are no duplicates in either column

Comment: @mozway yep, my bad. Would help if I knew how to read

Comment: I'm sure you do, maybe it's just time to go enjoy the sun/fresh air ;)

Comment: The task consists to iterate all rows of the dataframe and compare each row to other rows in the same dataframe and return likelihood.
As an example Dupont and Dupant the difference is a and o. 
Another exmple is 015220 and 015221. The difference is 1 and 0.

Comment: how do you define *likelihood*?

Comment: I used lkelihood to talk about when data looks alike.

Comment: @SANDWIDI sure, but this is **ambiguous** as it is

Comment: Please what is ambiguous, I could make you it clear for you!

Comment: a lot of things are ambiguous. For example, ``Dupont`` and ``Dupant`` differ only in ``a`` and ``o``. What about ``Dupont`` and ``dupant``? They differ in ``D`` and ``d`` and ``a`` and ``o``. Will it be included in your definition of likelihood? What about ``Dupont`` and ``Dupotn``? Such things are **ambiguous**

Comment: And what about ``Dupont`` and ``Dupon``, or ``Dupont`` and ``dupont`` just to mention some possibilities

Comment: you don't need to worry about D or d in Dupon and  dupant When we need here is to find the likelihood. Dupont,Dupon,dupont and Dupant are like the same.

Comment: That's exactly the problem here. On what base are you saying that _Dupont, Dupon, dupont, Dupant are like the same_? I take it as 1. Case insensitive, 2. If one letter is missing, it has to be exactly the same as the other, 3. The length of the word doesn't matter. What about dupont, dupotn, dpuotn, dupo?

Comment: If I have to use probability dupont, dupont, dupotn, dpuotn is 90% and dupo is 60%.

Comment: Characters number does not matter also case sensitivity does not matter. All thing I need is to return data which seems to be the same even one character is added or removed or the order is not respected. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried a few things and it is very complicated. The possibility of changing the letter combination is "endless" (well, it's basically not endless but n!, which is *a lot*). Things that I managed to put as condition:

1. case insensitivity
2. if **one character** of the provided word is **different**
3. if **one character** of the provided word is **missing**
4. if it is exactly the same

This is the combination which is considered *likelihood* by my code:

```py
['Dupont', 'dupont', 'upont', 'dpont', 'duont', 'dupnt', 'dupot', 'dupon']
['Dupant', 'dupant', 'upant', 'dpant', 'duant', 'dupnt', 'dupat', 'dupan']
['Darang', 'darang', 'arang', 'drang', 'daang', 'darng', 'darag', 'daran']
['BA', 'ba', 'a', 'b']
['Scatt', 'scatt', 'catt', 'satt', 'sctt', 'scat', 'scat']
['Sieb', 'sieb', 'ieb', 'seb', 'sib', 'sie']
['789985', '789985', '89985', '79985', '78985', '78985', '78995', '78998']
['789852', '789852', '89852', '79852', '78852', '78952', '78982', '78985']
['9852220', '9852220', '852220', '952220', '982220', '985220', '985220', '985220', '985222']
['015220', '015220', '15220', '05220', '01220', '01520', '01520', '01522']
['015221', '015221', '15221', '05221', '01221', '01521', '01521', '01522']
['10022', '10022', '0022', '1022', '1022', '1002', '1002']
```

Things that I can't seem to figure out the logic to write the if-statement:

1. if **character(s)** is/are **added** to the provided word --> Dupont, Duponts
2. if **more than one character** of the provided word is **different** --> Dupont, Dupants
3. if **more than one character** of the provided word is **missing** --> Dupont, Dupo
4. if the character are not in the **correct order** --> Dupont, Dpuont
5. .... a lot other that I didn't take into account rn

In regard to your statement:

*All thing I need is to return data which seems to be the same even one character is added or removed or the order is not respected*

This is not as simple as you think it is, in fact, this is very complicated.
There are a lot of what ifs that we haven't talk about, to mention some examples:

- 123456 --> 654321 (order is not respected)
- 123456 --> 123465 (order is not respected)
- 123456 --> 1234567 (one character is added)
- 123456 --> 123467 (one character is added, one character is missing)
- 123456 --> 7654321 (one character is added, order is not respected)
- Dupont --> Donut (one character is missing, order is not respected)
- Dupont --> Dont (two character is missing, order is respected)

Those are some examples that are not included in my code (will be filtered out and not seen as similar entries)

With that said, this is my code:

```py
name = ['Dupont', 'Dupant', 'Darang', 'BA', 'Scatt', 'Sieb']
ID = ['789985','789852','9852220','015220','015221','10022']

df = pd.DataFrame({'name': name, 'ID': ID})
print('This is df\n', df)
keys = list(df.keys())

keepindex = []
for col in range(len(keys)):
    allwords = []
    for i in range(len(df)):
        removeoneletteridx = []
        wordvariation = [df[f'{keys[col]}'][i], df[f'{keys[col]}'][i].lower()]
        for j in range(len(df[f'{keys[col]}'][i])):
            idxlist = list(range(len(df[f'{keys[col]}'][i])))
            idxlist.pop(j)
            removeoneletteridx.append(idxlist)
            word = ''.join([df[f'{keys[col]}'][i][x] for x in idxlist])
            wordvariation.append(word.lower())
        allwords.append(wordvariation)

    fulllist = []
    for i in range(len(df)):
        listtocompare = []
        for j in range(len(allwords)):
            for k in range(len(allwords[j])):
                if j != i:
                    listtocompare.append(allwords[j][k])
        fulllist.append(listtocompare)

    for i in range(len(allwords)):
        for j in range(len(allwords[i])):
            if allwords[i][j] in fulllist[i]:
                if i not in keepindex:
                    keepindex.append(i)
                break

new_df = df.iloc[keepindex,:]
print('\nThis is new_df\n',new_df)
```

The output given by the `print` commands is:

```
This is df
      name       ID
0  Dupont   789985
1  Dupant   789852
2  Darang  9852220
3      BA   015220
4   Scatt   015221
5    Sieb    10022

This is new_df
      name      ID
0  Dupont  789985
1  Dupant  789852
3      BA  015220
4   Scatt  015221
```

and to give some notes:

- from column `name`: `Dupont and Dupant` are considered the same
- from column `ID`: `789985 and 789852`, `015220 and 015221` are considered the same

If I go by this statement:

*All thing I need is to return data which seems to be the same even one character is added or removed or the order is not respected*

Then row 5 with `ID`: `10022` should be considered the same with `015220`, because `015220` --> `10022`: one character is missing, order is not respected

All things all, this kind of conditioning is very complicated. I am sure that my code missed a lot of things.